# How do I get this tuple using AbstractMap?

Tags: java, postgresql, collections, key-value

I am using PostgreSQL in Java and I'm executing the query, which selects coordinates from a Database.

Prior, the Points were saved in an `ArrayList`. Now I want to print out the Date with the Point. I want to get a Pair of Dates and Points via `AbstractMap` and print them out together.

But I don't know how to get the Dates and how to print the coordinates and Dates in one line.

Here is the relevant part of first class:

```
public ArrayList<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Point, Date>> getStartingPointCoordinates(String ab, String bis) {
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    ArrayList<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Point, Date>> list = new ArrayList<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Point,Date>>();

    String query = "select ST_Transform(target_cand_geom, 4326) as geom from fcd_osm_1day WHERE source_candidate_nr = ? and source_time between ? and ? ";

    try {
        // prepare statement
        connection = DatenbankAdapter.getInstance().getConnection();
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        statement.setInt(1, 1); // source_candiddate_nr = 1, weil dies immer dem Einstieg der Taxifahrt entspricht
        statement.setTimestamp(2, Timestamp.valueOf("2014-10-07 " + ab)); // hole alle daten von
        statement.setTimestamp(3, Timestamp.valueOf("2014-10-07 " + bis)); // hole alle daten bis

        resultSet = statement.executeQuery();

        /*
        * Add the geometry types to the connection. Note that you
        * must cast the connection to the pgsql-specific connection
        * implementation before calling the addDataType() method.
        */
        connection = ((DelegatingConnection) connection).getInnermostDelegate();
        ((org.postgresql.PGConnection) connection).addDataType("geometry", Class.forName("org.postgis.PGgeometry"));

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            Point geom = (Point) ((PGgeometry) resultSet.getObject(1)).getGeometry();
            list.add(geom);
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (resultSet != null)
                resultSet.close();
            if (statement != null)
                statement.close();
            if (connection != null)
                connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

Here is the test class:

```
public class DatenbankAdapterTest {

@Test
public void testCoordinateQuery() {
    DatenbankAdapter datenbankAdapter = DatenbankAdapter.getInstance();
    ArrayList<SimpleEntry<Point,Date>> objects = datenbankAdapter.getStartingPointCoordinates("00:00:00", "24:00:00");

    for (SimpleEntry<Point, Date> list : objects)
        System.out.println(list.getKey() + ", " + list.getValue());

    Assert.assertTrue(!objects.isEmpty());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a column source_time to the result set

```
String query = "SELECT ST_Transform(target_cand_geom, 4326) AS geom, "
        + "source_time "
        + "FROM fcd_osm_1day "
        + "WHERE source_candidate_nr = ? AND source_time BETWEEN ? AND ?";
...
Timestamp t  = resultSet.getTimestamp();
Date date = new Date(t.getTime()); // java.util.Date
list.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(geom, date));
```

Here a problem is hidden. `java.util.Date` is a date-time class. `java.sql.Date` is a child class that zeroes the time part. Hence the above solution.

It does not need telling that a Map.Entry is not nice. Better abuse from javafx the Pair class:

```
List<Pair<Point, Date>> getStartingPointCoordinates(String ab, String bis) {
    List<Pair<Point, Date>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
    return list;
```

BTW `Pair<K,V>` has the same getters: `K getKey()` and `V getValue()`.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your help. I am getting an error with the "Pair". I  imported javafx.util.*, but I was getting an Access restriction. Then I imported  javassist.compiler.ast as suggested by Eclipse. Then I got the error: "The type Pair is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Point,Date> in both classes.

Comment: Strange. Try `new javafx.util.Pair<Point, Date>(geom, date)` - for checking the right Pair class.

Comment: Still getting the same error, Access restriction. And the list.add.... doesnt work because its not applicable for the arguments (AbstractMap.SimpleEntry).

Comment: Then use SimpleEntry, I did not intend to cause that much extra work. ;)